# What is the topology of a helix

Tags: general-topology

Is the topology of a helix the same as or more similar to the topology of a cylinder or a torus? We can imagine the fundamental group of the torus looks like a square with 2  generators. Can we apply a shear to make a rhombus? Or is that not allowed in the system?

Comment: This question is jumping all over the place. A helix has the topology of the real line, so it's got the topology of a point. Now where did all these surfaces come from?

Comment: Maybe he meant helicoid, but that’s boring too.

Answer (score 1):

A helix actually has a rather boring topology, since it's homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. Its fundamental group is trivial.

Comment: I meant the type of helix that you get from twisting a wire. It has a thickness so it’s a surface.

Comment: @PhilipYeranosian That doesn’t matter for topology, for the most part. One just has to say “homotopy equivalent” instead of “homeomorphic.”

Comment: @PhilipYeranosian math terms have specific meaning. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Helix.html

Comment: Ok let’s forget about the helix. Let’s take the fundamental group diagram and shear it into a rhombus. Does that add any information?

Comment: If we take a line and a circle each is homeomotphic to R. Then if we take their product we get a surface homeomorephic to $R^2$. That’s what a cylinder is. Then if we take that cylinder and compose it with a helix we get a surface in $R^3$. And we can repeat this to get a surface in $R^n$. Will all of these will be homeomorphic to the real line?

Comment: @Philip A circle is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. The product of a circle and a line is not contractible. Unless you mean a filled in circle, which is a disc, which would give you something more like a wire bent into a helical shape. That's contractible, but not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$..